# KeyListener Methods Not Being Called

Tags: java, applet, keylistener

I made a extremely simple program to understand the workings of KeyListener, but for some reason none of my methods are being called when any key is hit. I would really appreciate if someone could give me some input.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class ClassOne extends Applet implements KeyListener {


    public void init(){
        this.addKeyListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Pressed");

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {
        System.out.println("Released");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: applet needs to have focus.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504906/keylistener-events-apparently-not-firing-in-java-applet

Comment: This is working fine for me exactly as you have it. Are you sure the applet has focus when you're typing?

Answer (score 1):

`KeyListener`s are designed to provide key notifications to the component that they registered to only when the component is focusable AND has focus. That means that it won't respond to key events if some other component has focus (or your component isn't focusable).

A better solution would be to use the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), but this would require you to use a `JApplet`, which the raises the question of, why are you using an `Applet` anyway...?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to set the following in init():

```
setFocusable(true);
```